# What makes a cymbal "dry" or "wet"?

Tags: drums, ride-cymbal, crash-cymbal

"Dry" seems like an odd term to use for a plate of hammered bronze. What makes a cymbal dry? If it's not dry, does that mean it is wet?

Comment: In what context? Dry & wet are ways to describe whether or not a channel/instrument/track has reverb or any other effect. Dry is without effect, wet is with [or even the effect only]; though it's a sliding scale with no absolutes.

Comment: @Tetsujin Good question. My question is in reference to a cymbal's tonality when played, not with reverberation as a consequence of the room or an added effect. A cymbal room at a drum store is purposely sound treated to allow the natural tone of the cymbal to be heard.

Comment: The more water you pour into the cymbal the more wet the sound will be. When the cymbal is dry it will have less H2O.

Answer (score 1):

In general wet will have more sustain. Dry will be dark with a very fast decay.

Simply put wet just rings more.

Comment: Careful -- now you need to define a "dark" vs. "bright" sound!   Also: could you clarify whether "sustain" and "rings" here means how long there's sound, or the amount of clear sound (as when hitting near the center) vs. the amount of white noise (hitting at the edge) ?